# If-Statement won't run and negates previous code

Tags: javascript

I've never used this site before and I'm new to programming so please bear with me.  My assignment requires me to prompt the user to enter a number between one and 12, ask again if they don't do that, and change the background color based on what number they enter.  Under 6 changes to red, 6 is white, and above 6 is blue.

For some reason, if I comment out the if/if-else/else block, the prompt before that works.  If I uncomment it, nothing happens on the web page at all and I don't know why.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>

        var userNum = window.prompt("Please insert a number between 1 and 12...", "1 - 12");

        if((userNum <= 12) && (userNum >= 1))
        {
            document.write
            (
                userNum + " * 1 = " + userNum * 1;
                userNum + " * 2 = " + userNum * 2;
                userNum + " * 3 = " + userNum * 3;
                userNum + " * 4 = " + userNum * 4;
                userNum + " * 5 = " + userNum * 5;
                userNum + " * 6 = " + userNum * 6;
                userNum + " * 7 = " + userNum * 7;
                userNum + " * 8 = " + userNum * 8;
                userNum + " * 9 = " + userNum * 9;
                userNum + " * 10 = " + userNum * 10;
                userNum + " * 11 = " + userNum * 11;
                userNum + " * 12 = " + userNum * 12;
            )

            if(userNum < 6)
            {
                window.bgColor = "red";
            }
            else if(userNum > 6)
            {
                window.bgColor = "blue";
            }
            else
            {
                window.bgColor = "white";
            }
        }
        else if((userNum > 12) || (userNum < 1))
        {
            window.alert("Error: Input value outside requested range");
            window.reload();
        }
        else
        {
            window.alert("Error: Input value not a number");
            window.reload();
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the console for errors? An error is thrown and your code doesn't execute (and that's why _"nothing happens on the web page"_), so when you comment the if-else part, there is no longer an error.

Comment: Aside from the logic error, you have fundamental syntax errors in the `document.write` call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i see the document.write problems, but i don't think this has the same logic error as the duplicate question

Comment: @NicholasTower: You're right, I misread the condition.

Comment: Why don't you try using JavaScript's `switch` function ?

Answer (score 1):

> If I uncomment it, nothing happens on the web page at all and I don't know why.

Use the debugging tools built into your browser. For instance, if you're using Chrome, read about its dev tools [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). A search for "XYZ dev tools" inserting your browser name will find information about your browser's dev tools.

One of the key ones is the console, which you can access via Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 on most OSs and via Cmd+Shift+I on Mac OS. In the console, you'd see a syntax error on the first `;` inside the `document.write` call, because you can't have a `;` in the middle of an expression like that. You probably also want to separate the lines you're outputting, so the **minimum** changes version might be:

```
var userNum = window.prompt("Please insert a number between 1 and 12...", "1 - 12");

if((userNum <= 12) && (userNum >= 1))
{
    document.write
    (
        userNum + " * 1 = " + userNum * 1 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 2 = " + userNum * 2 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 3 = " + userNum * 3 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 4 = " + userNum * 4 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 5 = " + userNum * 5 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 6 = " + userNum * 6 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 7 = " + userNum * 7 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 8 = " + userNum * 8 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 9 = " + userNum * 9 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 10 = " + userNum * 10 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 11 = " + userNum * 11 + "<br>" +
        userNum + " * 12 = " + userNum * 12 + "<br>"
    );

    if(userNum < 6)
    {
        window.bgColor = "red";
    }
    else if(userNum > 6)
    {
        window.bgColor = "blue";
    }
    else
    {
        window.bgColor = "white";
    }
}
else if((userNum > 12) || (userNum < 1))
{
    window.alert("Error: Input value outside requested range");
    window.reload();
}
else
{
    window.alert("Error: Input value not a number");
    window.reload();
}
```

**But** some other notes:

- In general, avoid `document.write`. It's more useful to use the DOM API (or a wrapper library for it like jQuery) to show information on a page.
- Your second `if` is redundant unless you're intentionally allowing for users entering non-numbers and relying on comparisons with `NaN` always being false.
- The `bgColor` property is long-since deprecated and superceded by CSS. So `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "color-goes-here";`.

Comment: That was all it took, thank you.  The window doesn't reload as I thought it would but I can probably figure that out.  I only use document.write for this class I'm taking now.  I'm fairly sure the professor uses it to illustrate properties and structure of the BOM and DOM.  However, do you think you could explain more about why my second if statement is redundant?